# How to get the sign-in options without first getting a recommendation?

Tags: google-identity-toolkit, google-identity

So I am trying to implement Google Identity Toolkit for my website.
Now what happens is when I try to login and put up my Email Id,

1. If its a gmail id, it directly goes into google login.
2. If any other domain is used, then we get options to sign-in using google,microsoft,facebook,etc

Link for reference: https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/

But my problem is people using facebook generally login with their gmail id and so on.

So how to modify the toolkit so as to have all the options of signing in available along with the email-id text box (just like it is in google idenitity toolkit v1 but I can't use it since it does not have facebook as an Identity provider)?

Also, I would like to have the widget for login appear without using the initial sign-in button.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To load the widget without using the sign-in button, you can simply create a link to the location of your widget with the additional query parameter `mode=select`, as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/setup-frontend#page_with_sign_in_widget). You can redirect to that link as you wish, e.g. after the user clicks a sign in button of your own making.

There is currently no way of displaying other login options alongside the email box. The reason for this user experience is [documented](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/federated-login) on the Identity Toolkit site.

Comment: Seems right. I have been through the documentation but I was wondering if there still was a way.

Comment: @dsalama, Asking for just the email first and then recommending login options is fine but why force the users with Gmail addresses to sign in with Google? Maybe this particular website is for professional networking and the users like to sign in with LinkedIn. They would still want to use their Gmail address for email exchanges but would like to connect their LinkedIn profile and network with this website.

Comment: @Price I agree with your point. I find the design of GIT login flow somewhat illogical. It simply isn't designed the way most users think of registering / signing in and managing accounts online.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **hacky recipe** I've been using for my preliminary website toolkit integration testing:

- in the initial widget screen if you already have listed the email account you'd like to use but with a different/non-native IDP just select `+Add account` which leads you to the email-only input screen
- in the email-only input screen enter a **fake** email, like `test@example.com`, which will not match any of the IDPs and thus will send you to the email + IDP selection screen
- in the email + IDP selection screen just replace the fake email address with the real one and select the desired provider.

**Warning:** once a selection is done it *appears* to remains the "prefered" one, I'm not sure if it's really persistent and/or it can be changed later on via `Manage Account`, I saw a `You may remove any except the first` note in there (still on my todo list to check out the details).

But IMHO this awkward recipe is not suited for actual users in production, except maybe as a workaround solution available via support/faq for those insisting on not using the 'native' IDP matching their email (I'm still wondering why would they do that).